# ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override' .solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, function-override

Can someone please help me in understanding why i am getting this error I am new to solidity and unable to resolve this have tried the way written in documentation too and getting the same error.

> ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'
> function currentTime() internal view override returns (uint) {
> ^------^

I am trying to override **Parent** contract's ***currentTime()***  in **Child**. like below.

```
//Parent.solc

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Parent{
    
    enum State { Ongoing, Failed, Succeeded, PaidOut }

    string public name;
    uint public targetAmount;
    uint public fundingDeadline;
    address public beneficiary;
    State public state;
    mapping(address => uint) public amounts;
    bool public collected;
    uint public totalCollected;

    modifier inState( State expectedState ){
        require(state == expectedState, "Invalid State");
        _;
    }

    constructor (
        string memory contractName,
        uint targetAmountEth,
        uint durationInMin,
        address beneficiaryAddress
    )  {
        name = contractName;
        targetAmount = targetAmountEth * 1 ether;
        fundingDeadline = currentTime() + durationInMin * 1 minutes;
        beneficiary = beneficiaryAddress;
        state = State.Ongoing;
    }

    function contribute() public payable inState(State.Ongoing) {
        amounts[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        totalCollected += msg.value;

        if(totalCollected >= targetAmount){
            collected = true;
        }
    }

// ***         THIS IS THE FUNCTION               ***//
// ***   I NEED TO OVERRIDE IN MY CHILD CONTRACT  ***//

    function currentTime() internal virtual view returns(uint) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }
}
```

I am trying to import the above contract into child.sol as :-

```
//Child.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "./Parent.sol";

contract Child is Parent{
    uint time;

    constructor (
        string memory contractName,
        uint targetAmountEth,
        uint durationInMin,
        address beneficiaryAddress
    )
        Parent(contractName, targetAmountEth, durationInMin, beneficiaryAddress)
    {
        
    }

 // *** HERE I AM TRYING TO OVERRIDE *** //

    function currentTime() internal view override returns (uint) {
        return time;
    }

    function setCurrentTime(uint newTime) public {
        time = newTime;
    }
}
```

I am using truffle with solc version 0.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution just need to install previous version of solc in truffle folder.

Use solc version v0.5.16

can change it by adding

```
compilers: {
       solc: {
           **version: "0.5.16"** 
       }
   }
```

after the network.
or if this doesn't work go to the file where truffle is installed and change the solc version in package.json add it like ^0.5.16.

Comment: Please indicate which version of solc did you use to fix the problem.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for pointing this out just edited my answer